# Correct size of Window type for XGetWindowProperty

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I am reading the `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` atom from the root window, using this code:

```
Atom actualType;
int actualFormat;
unsigned long nItems, bytesAfter;
unsigned char * value;

if (XGetWindowProperty(display, window, atom, 0, LONG_MAX / 4,
                       False, XA_WINDOW,
                       &actualType, &actualFormat,
                       &nItems, &bytesAfter, &value) != Success ||
    actualType != XA_WINDOW) {
    return NULL;
}

Window result = *(Window*)value;    /*  <=== this line seems dubious */
XFree(value);
return result;
```

However, although it works, I am pretty sure it is bugged, because adding a few printfs shows that:

- `sizeof(Window)` is 8
- `actualFormat` is 32
- `nItems` is 1

Therefore, according to the documentation, the buffer allocated for the property is 4 bytes long. Reading a Window from it is a blatant overflow.

So what's the deal with that? Is there some flags I miss to make `Window` only 4 bytes? Should I read the value as an `uint32_t` and cast it to `Window` after? Anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation (XGetWindowProperty(3)) states that:

> If the specified format is 32, the property data must be a long array.

The include file shows `Window` as a typedef to `XID` which is a typedef to `unsigned long`.

I would guess that the use of 32 is an anachronism and used to mean 32-bits, but now means whatever your compiler chooses to use for `unsigned long`.

Comment: Wow. I did not read it that way but it's pretty plausible. I'll try to locate the relevant code in Xlib to check that.

Comment: You're right. The 8/16/32 values are just used in a switch and mapped to `sizeof(char)`/`sizeof(short)`/`sizeof(long)`. [Here](https://github.com/mirror/libX11/blob/master/src/GetProp.c#L107). So they do not match their respective type's actual size.

Comment: Worth noting that on the wire, it's still actually 32 bits. The value gets zero-extended to an unsigned long by XGetWindowProperty.